# Form submit after multiple tasks are completed in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a form submit function after multiple tasks are completed.

The tasks can be completed in any order.

I tried solving it like this:

```
function callbackWhenCompleted(callback) {
  let tasks = {
    imageUploaded: false,
    submitButtonClicked: false
  };

  function taskCompleted(taskName) {
    tasks[taskName] = true;
    if (Object.values(tasks).every(Boolean)) {
      callback();
    }
  }

  return taskCompleted;
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.taskCompleted = callbackWhenCompleted(this.submitForm);
  }

  imageUploaded = () => this.taskCompleted('imageUploaded');
  submitButtonClicked = () => this.taskCompleted('submitButtonClicked');
  submitForm = () => { /* */ }
  render() { /* */ }
}
```

What are some better ways of solving this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `imageUploaded` and `submitButtonClicked` in your `Form` component state instead and check if both are true after you change one of them and call `submitForm` if that's the case.

**Example**

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    imageUploaded: false,
    submitButtonClicked: false
  };

  imageUploaded = () => {
    this.setState({ imageUploaded: true }, this.checkIfComplete);
  };

  submitButtonClicked = () => {
    this.setState({ submitButtonClicked: true }, this.checkIfComplete);
  };

  checkIfComplete = () => {
    const { imageUploaded, submitButtonClicked } = this.state;

    if (imageUploaded && submitButtonClicked) {
      this.submitForm();
    }
  };

  submitForm = () => {
    // ...
  };

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```